# Is it bad practise to use Stream.ofNullable to process a nullable List

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type

Item 12 in this [using optionals correctly is not optional](https://dzone.com/articles/using-optional-correctly-is-not-optional) article states

> Sometimes, we tend to "over-use" things. Meaning that we have a thing,
>   like Optional, and we see a use case for it everywhere. In the case of
>   Optional, a common scenario involves chaining its methods for the
>   single purpose of getting a value. Avoid this practice and rely on
>   simple and straightforward code.

Is the same true for `Stream.ofNullable`? Should I avoid this:

```
Stream.ofNullable(getHandlers(...))
   .flatMap(Collections::stream)
   .forEach(handler -> handler.handle(event));
```

In favour of this?

```
List<Handler> handlers = getHandlers(...) 

if (handlers == null) {
    return; // do nothing
}

handlers.forEach(handler -> handler.handle(event));
```

Comment: I think the bad practice here is to have `getHandlers(...)` return null. Just return an empty list if there are no handlers.

Comment: (*Effective Java* has an item about returning empty lists instead of null. It's Item 54 in 3rd Ed, 43 in 2nd Ed)

Comment: As said by others, having a nullable list is already bad practice. Additionally, `Stream.ofNullable(…) .flatMap(Collections::stream)` has significant performance drawbacks.

Comment: @Holger _significant_?

Comment: @Eugene depending on the actual operation; it’s eliminating the size information (think of, e.g. `toArray()`), as well sorted and distinct flags, if present, and destroying any parallel capability (at least in the reference implementation where only the outer streams splitting capability matters).

Comment: @Holger indeed... thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the advice of "rely on simple and straightforward code" is good advice anywhere, not limited to either `Optional` or `Stream.ofNullable`.

In terms of the specific choice in the question: I think it is very hard to say that one is objectively simpler and more straightforward than the other. `Stream.ofNullable` is more concise, but requires you to know what it does; the explicit `if` check is more verbose, but is probably easier to understand if you are unfamiliar with `Stream`s.

When new methods are introduced to an API, one can argue that it is in some sense "harder", because people unfamiliar with the API method will find it harder to read, because they won't know what that method does. Of course, one could counter they *ought* to know it, or should expect to encounter things they don't know.

So, I'm basically saying that you should use the one you/readers of your code will feel most comfortable with.

---

However, the thing I think is bad practice here is for `getHandlers(...)` to be returning null in the first place. There is an item in *Effective Java* (Item 54 in 3rd Ed, 43 in 2nd Ed) about always returning an empty list instead of null.

This advice works perfectly here, since you are handling a null list in the same way as you would an empty list.

Doing this would allow you to write:

```
List<Handler> handlers = getHandlers(...);
handlers.stream().forEach(...);
```

which is objectively simpler code.

I think it would be even better to use:

```
for (Handler h : getHandlers(...)) {
  // ...
}
```

because you have more flexibility to do more inside the loop (e.g. breaking), without using streams(/stream-like methods) at all.

Comment: "`Stream.ofNullable` is more concise". With a collection as parameter that you need to stream as here I disagree. And that is also looks less straight to read than a fail fast/early return.  Something like `Stream<T> Stream.ofNullable(Collection<T> collection)` that stream for you the collection if not empty would make more sense IMHO. But that doesn't exist in built in classes. But I agree completely for the second part.